# Invoking Angular Language Service from cmd

Tags: angular, angular-language-service

How can i invoke angular language service from command line or from a script. Like we have eslint plugin which we can install as vscode extension and install in node modules and access it in our code like below:

```js
const { ESLint } = require('eslint')
const eslint = new ESLint()
const results = await eslint.lintFiles(filesToCheck)
const filteredResults = ESLint.getErrorResults(results)
```

The same approach for angular language service to detect the issues in a custom html file
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need this? You can just build/serve the project and you'll see any problems that are there.

Comment: My application is very big and build takes long time. I want a pre-hook feature such a way when any developer pushing any change only check that files and it dependents alone. I achieved that desired results in linting only specific files they changed and need the same way for Angular Language service too. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that's possible currently because there seem to be no documentation on it. But you can check the source code for the language service and see if you can find anything about it.